# Changing image on hover and back using fade

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to change an image on hover and back again.

The idea is that when I hover over an image, it fades into a different image and when my mouse leaves, the image fades back to the original.

Here is what I have tried so far, using jQuery:

```
<img src="https://www.shareicon.net/data/128x128/2015/08/17/86675_cat_256x256.png" />

<script>

$("img").hover(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log("hover");

    $("img").fadeOut(400, function() {
        $("img").attr("src", "http://files.softicons.com/download/animal-icons/meow-icon-set-by-iconka/png/128x128/cat_purr.png")
    }).fadeIn(400, function() {
        $("img").attr("src", "https://www.shareicon.net/data/128x128/2015/08/17/86675_cat_256x256.png")
    });
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can actually do this with plain CSS and it would be more efficient.

Just create a div, put both images inside, absolute position so one is on top of another, and when hover apply opacity: 0 with a transition to the front image.

You can achieve this with position absolute, z-index, and hover pseudo selector.

```css
.container{
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
}

img{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.img-top{
  z-index: 999999;
  transition: 0.3s linear all;
}

.img-top:hover{
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img class="img-bottom" src="https://www.cesarsway.com/sites/newcesarsway/files/d6/images/askthevet/checklist.jpg" alt="">
  <img class="img-top" src="https://i.ebayimg.com/images/g/k2gAAOSwT5tWKhVS/s-l300.jpg" alt="">
</div>
```

Comment: I don't have much CSS experience with animations. Do you have a code snippet I could refer to?

Comment: I just updated my answer with a code snippet achieving what you need :)

Comment: I just noticed that the URL to your second image is an URL to download the image, so that URL is not gonna work